# Getting specific key values | JSON | C#

Tags: c#, json

How do I manage to filter after specific key values in a json file? I am using C#.
I want to get every distance.value and save them into an array of doubles. That way I want to create a distance matrix.

Stackoverflow wants me to add more information but I am not sure what additional code snippets are useful. If I am missing something I will add it to the comments.

Here is the json output.

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [],
   "origin_addresses" : [],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 m",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 Minute",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "5 m",
                  "value" : 5
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 Minute",
                  "value" : 1
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "3,7 km",
                  "value" : 3730
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "10 Minuten",
                  "value" : 582
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "0,5 km",
                  "value" : 510
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 Minuten",
                  "value" : 182
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 m",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 Minute",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "3,7 km",
                  "value" : 3725
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "10 Minuten",
                  "value" : 581
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }    
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe you already looped over the file entries to get the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
var json = "_YOUR_JSON_";
var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
var doubles = jobject.SelectTokens("$.rows[*].elements[*].distance.value")
    .Values<double>()
    .ToArray();
```

Notes:

- The query string `rows[*]` contains the [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) wildcard operator `[*]`. This operator matches all array elements under the parent element "rows".
- Same as previous for `elements[*]`
- `distance.value` - path to required value
- As long as `SelectTokens` returns `IEnumerable<JToken>` we need to cast our values to double, so call `Values<double>()`
- Finally cast our `IEnumerable<double>` to array.

Comment: Thanks alot!! My double looks like this: var result = new double[numStops, numStops]; How can I convert it to an two dimensional array.?

Comment: You want an two dimensional array with same values?

Comment: Yeh similiar to a distance matrix.                                                                               
  for (int j = 0; j < (numStops*numStops);){
                for (int i = 0; i < numStops; i++){
                    for (int h = 0; h < numStops; h++){
                        result[i,h] = arr[j];
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }